# AWS lambda event spec for different sources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Where can I find a spec (list of field names and values) for events incoming to an AWS lambda?

The events have different fields depending on the source (for example Kinesis, S3, etc), and sometimes it's not clear what is available in each event except by trial and error.

Comment: I think you need to refer specific service lambda event structure, example, for S3: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Nambari Yes, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refer specific service Event Structure to understand the fields. For example [S3 Event Strucutre](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) and [Cognito events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-events.html).

[This Tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html) has comprehensive list of possible event sources and links to details about those.